# What is the time complexity of applying Binary searching algorithm for insertion in Heap?

Tags: algorithm

I am not able to understand that if I apply binary search algo for making insertions in Heap then how to approach for calculating time complexity of this algo ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're using binary search when inserting into a heap?

Comment: Insertion in heaps tends to be to the bottom right-most node, then following a percolating/bubbling process for sort for amortized time. How are you using binary search?

Comment: @Radha, Is this your question? http://gateoverflow.in/1245/gate2007_47